# Foxx ArangoDB update data

Tags: arangodb, foxx

any one who used foxx and arango I want to update a document in a collection Inside post end point.
I'm new to arango I used collection.save(...) , to insert data I thought save() will update too if the given data containt the filed "_key" but When I test nothing is getting returned !
Any help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` is just for inserting data as [insert is an alias for save](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-documents-document-methods.html#insert--save)

for updating your data you need use [collection.update(selector, data)](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-documents-document-methods.html#update) method where selector can be `document-key` or `document-handle`

Comment: Thank You sir documentation helps me a lot